# Xcode - Get rid of a Team Member (which is myself)

Tags: xcode

I want to get rid of a Team Member (which is myself). I created it long time ago with a `Free` Role. I have bought an Apple Dev Account, which was also added to my Team in Xcode as an `Agent` Role. It is getting confusing while I have to chose between those two. I want to delete the `Free` role member. I tried to find it on Dev Port or Itunes Connect, without any success.

[image: Xcode Member]

Comment: did you try keychain ?

Comment: to delete some entries?not sure which one to delete, they all look similar.